# Is this interpretation of the Copenhagen Interpretation accurate in this book from Bruce Rosenblum and Fred Kuttner?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I'm very new on this particular subject, can anyone help me determine how accurate the interpretation of Bohr's quote is, and where is the origin of this quote?[image]

Comment: If the book itself doesn't give the source of the quote, that is a serious flaw of the book, beware and maybe get a better book. The problem with Copenhagen interpretation is that there is no unique presentation of it. There are some indications that Heisenberg had somewhat different understanding than Bohr had, and then later other people took hold of the term and put forward their ideas on what Copenhagen interpretation is. Nowadays many authors do not agree on what Copenhagen interpretation is about. This seems like a nice resource to start: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-copenhagen/

Comment: "*Is this interpretation of the Copenhagen Interpretation accurate in this book?*" - Are you asking for our interpretation of the book interpretation of the Copenhagen Interpretation? But how would we know what your interpretation of our interpretation is?

Comment: I'm still quite new on this subject so that I don't really have an interpretation, but I'm reading the Stanford articual which I think it is really helpful for my understanding. BTW, I was also asking the same question in Reddit, some of the fellows told me that I could disregard this book since it said atom does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from Niels Bohr's essay *Causality and Complementarity* from year 1958. You can find it in the book

Niels Bohr, *Essays 1958-1962 on Atomic Physics and Human Knowledge Volume III*, Wiley, 1963

Comment: I think this answer is very helpful in validating the quote's origin, but, if its subject was one upon which Bohr & Heisenberg differed, it might be hard to establish the quote's usefulness, given the earlier comment:  I believe Bohr initiated the Copenhagen interpretation, but Heisenberg may have had a greater influence on physics in general.  H. lived for about another 15 years after the  Bohr essay was written.